# Bootstrap 3 modal in react close button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap 3 in react project. In my project I created a component which shows a modal div. I will use this component in different parent components. The modal is showing after time lapse. The modal is showing fine but it is not dismissing. The close button is also not working.

parent component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Timer from './timer';


class Parent extends Component {


    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Timer />
            </div>
        ); }
    }


export default Parent;
```

child component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Timer extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            fin: false
        }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.myInterval = setInterval(() => {
            this.setState({fin: true})
        }, 10000);
    } 


    render() {

        const {fin} = this.state;

        if(fin){
            return (
                <div className="modal show">
        <div className="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
          <div className="modal-content">
            <div className="modal-header">
              <h5 className="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal 
              title</h5>

              <button type="button" name="test" className="close" onClick={this.handleClose} data-dismiss="modal" 
              aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div className="modal-body">
              ...
            </div>
            <div className="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" className="btn btn-secondary" data- 
               dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary">Save 
              changes</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

            )
        } else {
        return (
              <div>
                  Child counting...
              </div>
         )
        }
    }
}

export default Timer;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add a function for handling the close model, above render() in your child component.

```
handleClose()=>{
   this.setState({fin:false});
}
```